# why am I getting the error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ErrorException'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get all the values within a vector but whenever I run this code it just gives me an Error exception I don't know where the error is.

For everyone that is asking vector.h is apart of the [standford](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/doc/Vector-class.html) library

this is the [txtfile](https://easyupload.io/kq8wo7) I'm using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include "vector.h"  //You can also use #include <vector>

using namespace std;



Vector<string> split(string str, string token) //The saving grace
{
    Vector<string> result;
    while(str.size()){
        int index = str.find(token);
        if(index!=string::npos){
            result.push_back(str.substr(0,index));
            str = str.substr(index+token.size());
            if(str.size()==0)result.push_back(str);
        }
        else
        {
            result.push_back(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
bool isInteger(string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
      if(isdigit(str[i]) == true)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
//----------------------------------------------------//
//Lets get the text of the file into vectors
Vector<string> movieTitle(string txtfile)
{
  Vector<string> text; //Contains all of the text
  Vector<string> films; //All the films
  fstream myFile;
  string word;
  myFile.open(txtfile);
  if(!myFile.good())
  {
    cout << "ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  while(getline(myFile, word, '\n'))
  {
    //cout << word << endl;
    text += split(word, "\t");
  }
  for(int i = 0; text.size(); i++)
  {
    if(text[i].find("(") != string::npos && isInteger(text[i]))
    {
      films.push_back(text[i]);
    }
  }
  return films;
}

int main()
{
  Vector<string> test;
  test = movieTitle("movies_mpaa.txt");
  cout << test << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

> Out Put:
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ErrorException'
> what():
> Aborted (core dumped)

I am just confused on where the error is occurring.

Comment: what is `Vector` ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Vector is practically the same thing as #include <vector>

Comment: practically you should then remove it from your code and use `std::vector` instead

Comment: I wish but my professor wants to use vector.h

Comment: `isInteger` always returns on the first iteration. `isInteger("1asdasd") == true`

Comment: Have you tried to use a *debugger* to catch the exception, and see where it happens?

Comment: Important note: The [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function returns a non-zero value if the character is a digit. It might *not' be equal to `1` (which is the `int` value corresponding to `true`). So even if a character is a digit, your comparison might not succeed.

Comment: your professer may want it, but here we require you to post a [mcve]. Something that lets others reproduce the issue. If you do get the same error by using `std::vector` then there is no reason to use `Vector`. If you dont get the same error then we need to see contents of `vector.h`. In any case, please read about [mcve]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my proffessor hasnt taught us how to use the debugger on linux. I used GDB but it doesnt really tell me where my error is. It most likely is but I dont know how to use GDB

Comment: @Andyrew -- The debugger has no idea what the intention of your program is, so it cannot tell you automatically "you really meant to add 1, but you added 2" or whatever -- if that is what you are expecting, then you will be disappointed.  The purpose of the debugger is for you to use it to see if the program you wrote follows the plan you had.  If the code takes a different path than what you expected, or if a variable is set to a value you didn't expect, etc.  Only you know this -- the debugger is just there to make it easier to "trace" the program.

Comment: In higher education there's a reliance of students to do their own research. For example to learn how to use a debugger. A debugger is a *crucial* tool, and one you should learn as soon as possible. This might be the perfect time for that.

Comment: `Vector` seems to be quite different from `std::vector`. Eg it seems to have a `operator+=` to add elements. It will be difficult to help you, because not everybody has `Vector` available. If you can replace it with `std::vector` and the error is still there, you should really do that. We can help you to fix the issue, and then you can again go back to using `Vector` to make your prof happy

Comment: actually `Vector` is a little odd. Documentation says that it is ordered but at the same time it says that `push_back` adds the element at the end

Comment: @Andyrew Your `isInteger` is broken.  Using `return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit);` would be closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Something in `Vector` is throwing that exception, most likely as you index outside it. Look at `for(int i = 0; text.size(); i++)` until you spot the bug.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number hmm, looks like stanford docs are broken now.. several items list one thing in brief description and different thing in explanation.

Comment: @Andyrew Also, even if you didn't use the debugger, you made no attempt to output some intermediate values to see what they are to attempt to whittle the problem down to the line or set of lines that are causing the issue.  Instead, you wrote the program expecting it all to work, which is not what you should do, sans a debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ill go and watch a tutorial on GDB yeah Im sorry me not using a debugger was pretty dumb of me

Comment: @molbdnilo man im so dumb I forgot to put I<text.size(). This coding fatigue is starting to kick in. I have been coding for the past 8 hours

Comment: @Andyrew It's very important to take breaks and do something completely different, in particular when you're feeling stuck and frustrated. It's also much easier to see bugs in somebody else's code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your error:

```
   for(int i = 0; text.size(); i++)
   {
    if(text[i].find("(") != string::npos && isInteger(text[i]))
```

for-loop doesn't work like that, second expression is a boolean expression  which is checked against `true` before entering loop's body. Stanford library class `Vector::operator []` acts in same way as `std::vector`'s  and throws an exception if `i` becomes bigger than  `size()-1`. Your loop never stops because `size()` never would return 0 if it wasn't 0 to begin with, so eventually `i` becomes greater. Loop should look like

```
    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
```

If you used `backtrace` command in GDB after program had stopped, you'd saw  the chain of called functions leading to  catastrophic stop. You can walk up to your code by using  command `frame <number>`, where `<number>` would be an item in that list. GDB got extensive online documentation and  FAQ, there are god guides how to use it.